# With plan to upgrade to 16.04, 15.10 is better or 14.04 or the 16.04 beta?

Tags: upgrade

I understand that 16.04 is coming soon. 
I want to install a version that has easiest transition to 16.04.
Should I install 15.10 or 14.04 LTS or 16.04 beta?

Comment: Only you can answer this for you. I am on 16.04 and have been for a while myself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They're all equally as easy to upgrade to 16.04.

- 14.04 is LTS, so by default it only tells you about upgrades to other LTS versions, which come out every two years. 16.04 is an LTS version, so you should be prompted to 16.04, either on its release date (the 21st) or when 16.04.2 is released some time later.
- 15.10 is not LTS, so it prompts you to install any new version of Ubuntu that comes out. 15.10 is the version right before 16.04, so it will be a direct upgrade when 16.04 is released.
- I believe that the 16.04 beta will just transition into full 16.04 through updates. It may or may not say it wants to upgrade to a new version of Ubuntu, as it technically isn't. This might be the easiest upgrade path, but there's one problem.

Since 16.04 is still in beta, we cannot help you with any specific problems you may have before the final release on the 21st of April. The most we can do is redirect you to Launchpad to file a bug report.

For this reason, I suggest you hold off on installing 16.04 beta. The choice is yours between 14.04 and 15.10, but I'll give you some pointers to help make that choice.

- If your computer is relatively old (late 2013 or earlier), you're safe sticking with 14.04, and it might be the best option.
- If your computer is pretty new (some time after mid 2014), you may want to consider installing 15.10.

Remember, though, 15.10's default behavior of prompting to install every new version of Ubuntu *will* carry through to the 16.04 update, meaning you'll be asked to upgrade to 16.10 when it comes out and so on.

If you install 14.04 and upgrade it to 16.04, it will only next prompt you (by default, you can change it) to upgrade when 18.04 is released.

Comment: lts to lts upgrade is probably NOT going to be offered on the 21st. I believe that will happen when 14.04.2 is released.

Comment: @Rinzwind: Don't you mean **16**.04.2? 14.04.4 was just released, and 14.04.2 a long time ago...

Comment: yeah. 16.04.2...

Comment: @Rinzwind Ah, I'll take out the date

Comment: @Rinzwind: Also, I might be mistaken, but isn't 16.04.1 released before 16.04.2?

Comment: @ParanoidPanda no, silly, it's 16.04.1, 16.04.7, 16.04.4, _then_ 16.04.2!

Comment: Also, by installing regular updates on 16.04 Beta you will eventually get the full and final release of it. [It will not prompt you to upgrade again to the full version like it will on other versions.](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/04/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-15-10-to-16-04-lts)

Comment: @Zacharee1: 16.04.2 is released first and last? :D

Comment: @ParanoidPanda duhh (meant to type a 1)

Comment: @Rinzwind: Any source on the failing upgrade path from 14.04 and that they won't fix it before the release?

Comment: @Zacharee1 if the OP downloads 14.04 from the main Ubuntu download page, he will get 14.04.04.  That includes the 15.10 graphic stacks so he will get comparable performance even with a new computer, though admittedly some of the program version on other things will lag behind.  The advantage to him is that if he wants to wait for 16.04.02 to come out he will not have to upgrade until then, 14.04 will be supported while 15.10 expires soon.  Overall excellent answer so an enthusiastic  +1, just wanted to add that info as clarification.

Answer (score 1):

The direct answer to your question, which version is *easiest* to upgrade to 16.04, is the [Xenial daily build](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/).